# How do I pass JavaScript variables back to PHP?

Tags: 8, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to build a Drupal 8 module with a jQuery plugin. I wanted to pass some of the JavaScript variables to PHP so that I can save the variables into database.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4834132/how-to-pass-jquery-variable-to-drupal-ajax/) asked about the way to do it in Drupal 7. Since `hook_menu()` is gone in Drupal 8, how can I accomplish this task?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where you implemented `hook_menu()`, in Drupal 8 you need:

- A .routing.yml file containing the routing definition

  ```
  example.name:
    path: '/example/{variable}'
    defaults:
      _controller: '\Drupal\example\Controller\ExampleController::content'
    requirements:
      _permission: 'access content'
  ```
- A controller class for the page callback

  ```
  class ExampleController {  
    // ...
    public function content($variable) {
      // Do something with $variable.
    }
  }
  ```

What is important is the file structure, which should be as follows, assuming that *example* is the machine name of the module.

- example
  The directory containing the module

  - example.routing.yml
  - src
    The directory containing all the classes

    - Controller (directory)

      - ExampleController.php
        The file containing the controller

Keep in mind that you can change the machine name of the module, the route name (example.name), and the name of the class implementing the controller (ExampleController); the ones I used are only examples.